# Simulating Keyboard Presses with lazarus

Tags: python, bluetooth, keyboard, raspberry-pi2, lazarus

Basically I'm trying to make a wireless touch-screen keyboard to use with my Windows laptop.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/emulate-a-bluetooth-keyboard-with-the-raspberry-pi) to make a RPi 2 Model B emulate a Bluetooth keyboard and it worked by transmitting the keyboard presses from keyboard to PC via PiTooth (Python script used in [this tutorial](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/emulate-a-bluetooth-keyboard-with-the-raspberry-pi)).

With the script running I ran my Lazarus Application and none of the Virtual Keys pressed did/typed anything.

```
uses
Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls,
Buttons, MouseAndKeyInput, LCLType, ExtCtrls;
```

...

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton11Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  KeyInput.Press(VK_7);
end;
```

I spent a lot of time surfing, digging, trial and error and made the following observations:

1. PiTooths keymap.py `"KEY_7" : 36,` and Lazarus `VK_7 = $37;`. I tried adding `VK_7 : $37,` to keymap.py but it didn't recognize the `$` character which resulted in an error that stopped PiTooth.py from starting.
2. While PiTooth.py is running via terminal, characters typed using a physical keyboard show in the terminal and received by my PC
3. While PiTooth.py is running via terminal, characters typed using matchbox-keyboard show in the terminal but aren't sent to or received by my PC
4. With PiTooth.py running in terminal, buttons clicked on using Lazarus TSpeedButton with underlying code `KeyInput.Press(VK_7);` do not show in the terminal and aren't sent to or received by my PC

I tried searching for alternatives for `KeyInput.Press(VK_7);` but no luck in Lazarus although I read that Delphi has a function called `xsendkey` and `keybd_event` and Python has `uinput` but I need the GUI abilities of Lazarus.

Possible to use Python functions like `uinput` in Lazarus?

Not sure what to do at this point. Any and all help is appreciated. Been at this for over 3 months :'(

Note: the touch-screen I'm using is resistive and is recognized as a mouse click when touched.

Btw I'm relatively new to Linux and programming in general but have a somewhat decent understanding if that means anything lol